# Azure reactjs deployment best practices

Tags: reactjs, azure, kubernetes, azure-web-app-service

Me and my team are working on a product deployed in Azure, **all of our backend services will be deployed by using k8s service in Azure** and it seems like the most pragmatic and right choice for us. 
We also have ReactJS frontend for some of backend services. We deploy them by using Docker and k8s at this moment. **We started thinking about scaling of our web apps and found that everything can be done by Azure Web Apps.** 
I would like to know what is best practice of web app deployment in Cloud(Azure in my case):

1. Should I use Azure Web App service for this purpose?
2. Or it is better to keep everything in my k8s cluster

Any link or a book as source of true might be even better :)

**Update 1:**

I also found out that web apps can be deployed by using Blob Storage and Azure functions to access the static content from the Blob Storage. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Azure WebApp is a perfect option for your requirement check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service/app-service-web-overview#why-use-web-apps) for more details and guide

Comment: I see that it has Docker deployment and as we already have Docker images, it might make sense to use it, but I cannot find any information how it can be scaled if I use Docker as a base

Comment: Suggesting you to check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker-go

Comment: what do you think about the option I added in the main post?